# Prevent formatting of minified JavaScript files in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, minify

Recently I have started using of PyCharm so I am newbie in this IDE. Usually I format whole project at once it works pretty good BUT it has one problem: it formats all minified files so appears additional lines in them.

My question is how to prevent this action? Is there some hacks?

I use PyCharm 3.4 Mac OS version.

Comment: 1) By "format" you mean `Code | Reformat Code...` ? 2) Full IDE version (build number in particular)? -- can be taken from `Help | About`?

Comment: 1) Yes.
2) PyCharm 3.4.1 Build #PY-135.1057

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, *but it will NOT work in your PyCharm version (build 135.1057)* -- it has to be **build 138.473 or newer**). At the moment there is no newer version available of PyCharm (even [EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview+%28EAP%29)).

---

**There is no dedicated settings where you can provide list of patterns/file extensions that should be omitted during code reformat (that would affect whole project by default) at the moment.**

`Reformat Code` functionality was enhanced in newer builds (branch 138.xxx). With **[IDEA-59850](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59850)** being implemented (**build 138.473 or newer**), it is now possible to **use custom scopes** when reformatting the code -- you just define custom scope (`Preferences | Scopes` -- where you either include all desired files .. or exclude all unwanted files) and then use it in corresponding dialog instead of whole project/selected file or folder.

If you check comments in that ticket ([IDEA-59850](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59850)) you will see that it is exactly about your case -- avoid reformatting already minified or other not-to-be-touched files.

**Please note:** invoking `Reformat Code` from Editor shows one dialog, while invoking the same from Project View shows different one where scope option is available (actual screenshot is from PhpStorm, where this functionality is already available):

[image]

---

Therefore you have to wait for next major PyCharm version (be it 4.0 or maybe even 3.5) to have this functionality available.

**P.S.**
Related ticket (maybe it will provide settings for the whole project, so no need to worry about "do not forget to choose right scope"):

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97848

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. I have downloaded my version few days ago. Will try you option.